# gcc linker errors on fedora: undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker, fedora

I'm trying to compile/run my program (which is working fine on Windows/MSVC) on Fedora/gcc. Compilation is fine now, linking seems to be a problem. Based on symptoms and this post [undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751640/undefined-reference-to-gxx-personality-sj0), it seemed to me that the problem *might* be some mismatch in compiler/linker arch type. Anyway, I'm no expert so

- I just uninstalled everything I found with `yum list | egrep gcc|g++|c++` using `yum remove` and
- then ran `yum install gcc gcc-c++`.

NOTES:

- All output you see below is AFTER steps above.
- Last line of gcc output is: `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
- Code is compile clean, no warnings/errors.
- Almost all undefined references are to names in `namespace std`
- I have only one source file `Main.C` (and 2 headers).

I've tried to provide all the info I could think of, let me know if you need anymore info.

```
[root@myTestMachine kash]# ls -Altr
total 44K
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.5K Sep 11 11:34 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.6K Sep 11 13:50 MyCommon.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.5K Sep 11 14:01 Main.cpp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  26K Sep 11 14:02 sort.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   80 Sep 11 14:26 a.cpp
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# gcc -c -std=c++0x Main.cpp
[root@myTestMachine kash]# echo $?
0
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# rm Main.o
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# gcc -std=c++0x Main.cpp
/tmp/cckR4oL1.o: In function `main::{lambda(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)#1}::operator()(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) const':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x270): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const'

..... LOTS of other such undefined refs; see complete list on pastebin link below .....

Main.cpp:(.text._ZSt10_ConstructISsISsEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZSt10_ConstructISsISsEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x37): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)'
/tmp/cckR4oL1.o:(.eh_frame+0x1cb): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
```

**Complete gcc output here: http://pastebin.com/PvycFHQM**

---

```
[root@myTestMachine kash]# uname -a
Linux myTestMachine 3.1.0-7.fc16.i686.PAE #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 20:53:45 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# yum list gcc gcc-c++
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Installed Packages
gcc.i686                                               4.6.3-2.fc16                                           @updates
gcc-c++.i686                                           4.6.3-2.fc16                                           @updates
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# rpm -qa | grep gcc
gcc-4.6.3-2.fc16.i686
libgcc-4.6.3-2.fc16.i686
arm-gp2x-linux-gcc-4.1.2-12.fc15.i686
gcc-c++-4.6.3-2.fc16.i686
arm-gp2x-linux-gcc-c++-4.1.2-12.fc15.i686
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# rpm -qa | grep g++
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# rpm -qa | grep c++
libsigc++20-2.2.10-1.fc16.i686
libstdc++-devel-4.6.3-2.fc16.i686
libstdc++-4.6.3-2.fc16.i686
gcc-c++-4.6.3-2.fc16.i686
arm-gp2x-linux-gcc-c++-4.1.2-12.fc15.i686
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# rpm -qa | grep ld
rpm-build-libs-4.9.1.2-1.fc16.i686
libldb-1.1.0-1.fc16.i686
openldap-2.4.26-1.fc16.1.i686
[root@myTestMachine kash]# rpm -qa | grep -w ld
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# ld -version
GNU ld version 2.21.53.0.1-6.fc16 20110716
Copyright 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
[root@myTestMachine kash]#
[root@myTestMachine kash]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[root@myTestMachine kash]#
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
gcc -std=c++0x Main.cpp
```

Do this instead:

```
g++ -std=c++0x Main.cpp
```

Or do this instead:

```
gcc Main.cpp -lstdc++
```

The bottom line is: make sure that you either use "g++" or "-lstdc++" **at the link stage**. You can use either front end during the compile stage.