# "undefined reference" (works on linux, but not with cygwin on windows)

Tags: c++, boost, reference, cygwin, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gcc linker errors on fedora: undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376897/gcc-linker-errors-on-fedora-undefined-reference)

Since I've had trouble with the VC++ (a function overload that doesn't happen with gcc, since my project partner is programming on Linux), i switched to gcc on cygwin, but I am having trouble getting the programm running here too (him being able to compile the same code without any problems)

I am trying to compile with

```
$ gcc -I D:/Programme/Boost_Library/boost_1_51 ABI_new.cpp -o ABI
```

And afterwards I get a huge amount of errors like that:

```
/tmp/ccO4eSA2.o:ABI_new.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to ´std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const'
    /tmp/ccO4eSA2.o:ABI_new.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned int) const'
    /tmp/ccO4eSA2.o:ABI_new.cpp:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned int) const'
    /tmp/ccO4eSA2.o:ABI_new.cpp:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned int) const'
```

I am not sure if this could have to do anything with the program not being able to read the input file apparently (indicated by the exit status), but I don't know, why that wouldn't work either, since - again - my colleague has no problems with exactly the same code.

I would really appreciate any tipps.

Comment: Try compiling with `g++` instead of `gcc`. The latter might not know about the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try compiling with `g++` instead of `gcc`. The latter probably does not know about the C++ standard library, and is failing to instruct the linker to link it in.

Comment: Thank you very much. What a stupid mistake ^^