# Creating a class in C++ error

Tags: c++

I have a test class, it has nothing in it apart from the bones of a class.

h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_


class Test
{
public:
    Test();
};

#endif /* TEST_H_ */
```

cpp

```
#include "test.h"

Test::Test()
{
}
```

And then in my main class I have:

```
Test *test = new Test();
```

I also include test.h.

I get the error:

```
 Undefined reference to Test::Test()
```

Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: You're not linking your implementation and you're using an unnecessary pointer with unnecessary dynamic memory allocation. C++ also has no main class, it has a `main` function.

Comment: In my main class, the class that calls test, it is linked to other classes

Comment: @chris could you elaborate "You're not linking your implementation"

Comment: How do you compile/link it? And again, there's but one class here, and that's `Test`.

Comment: Ok, so it's in an IDE. I'd wager you haven't put all three files into a project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc linker errors on fedora: undefined reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376897/gcc-linker-errors-on-fedora-undefined-reference)

Comment: @ chris, they are in a project

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, even after cleaning the project and restarting the IDE it still wouldn't work. I had to manually add in test.h and test.cpp to my config.pri