# Qt error, personality routine

Tags: c++, qt, undefined

I am trying to build a Qt project in Windows XP 32 bit using Qt 4.8.4 and Qt Creator 2.6.2. After getting hundreds of thousand of issues there are 2 errors reported by the compiler:

```
c:\Qt\4.8.4\lib\libqtmaind.a(qtmain_win.o)(.eh_frame+0x12):-1: In function`Z4qMinIiERKT_S2_S2_':

..\..\src\corelib\thread\qbasicatomic.h:95: error: undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'

:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

An ideas how to fix this ?

OS: Windows XP 32 bit with MingW compiler.

Comment: These problems are a result of mismatched compiler/standard library versions between your main code and the compiler/standard library used to compile the QT binary. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7751743/485561).

Comment: Thanks, I was using multiple versions of g++ in my system path. Keeping only the one of MingW fixed the problem.

Comment: Use MinGW 4.4 with Qt 4.8.4.