# Compiling or using RtMidi on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, compilation, midi

The docs for RtMidi have example compiler commands for Linux and OSX, but not Windows. It just says that it depends on the compiler. I can find no such example anywhere on the Internet.

I am trying every combination I can think of and finding that RtMidi.cpp in fact references things that are supposed to be in the Windows API, but my computer isn't finding them. The docs say winmm.lib is needed, but this doesn't exist for me; winmm.dll does, but it will not link. I'm using MinGW. The RtMidi documentation offers no information on how to compile a sample program with RtMidi on Windows. First it says to use MinGW, then it says to use a VisualStudio project, but there is no actual example of a command in either case. I have been reading for days, searching through header files, debugging, and in my searches I keep seeing references on this site to other people having problems using RtMidi - but who have compiled it. I am only using g++ as provided by MinGW; I don't want to create a project file, configure, make, etc., as the program I want to make will have about 100 lines of code. I tried doing configure and make from MSYS, but it gave me a Unix executable.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: Specifically: `C:\MinGW\bin>"g++.exe" -Wall -D__WINDOWS_MM__ -I"C:\MinGW\include" -I"C:\Users\chuckk\Downloads\rtmidi-2.1.0\tests" -L"C:\Users\chuckk\Downloads\rtmidi-2.1.0\tests" -o midiprobe C:\Users\chuckk\Downloads\rtmidi-2.1.0\tests\midiprobe.cpp C:\Users\chuckk\Downloads\rtmidi-2.1.0\tests\RtMidi.cpp`
gives:
`C:\Windows\TEMP\ccQsL07P.o:RtMidi.cpp:(.text+0x11c9): undefined reference to `midiInAddBuffer@12'`
midiInAddBuffer IS defined in mmsystem.h, included by RtMidi.cpp and in C:\MinGW\include. Why is it telling me it's undefined? Later ld.exe fails with 1, but doesn't say where.

Comment: I figured out a step. libwinmm.a is in MinGW/lib. For some reason, however a search for 'winmm' in that folder comes up with no results. I couldn't find it until I searched each folder. I added that folder and library, and those particular undefined references went away. Now I'm stuck on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751640/undefined-reference-to-gxx-personality-sj0 so I will try to make sense of the suggestions there.

Comment: I'm trying to compile rtmidi on win 7 as part of a dependency (for VCVRack). I've tried using the --with-winmm option on configure, but it fails. I've tried modifying the makefile to use: AC_MSG_RESULT(using WinMM)
    LIBS="-lwinmm ${LIBS}"
    api="$api -D__WINDOWS_MM__"  how (if you did) did you get this to configure and compile?